# How to get the TimeZoneOffset ID from TimeZone value in Java 8?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

I have `TimeZone` as, let's say `Asia/Kolkata`, how to get the corresponding `ZoneOffset` ID, ie., `+05:30` from this in Java?

I have been trying the below, but no win:

```
String zoneOffsetID = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata").getId();
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of(zoneOffsetID);
```

I also tried `Asia/Calcutta` which I got from:

```
Set<String> allZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
```

Comment: You may be looking for `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata").getRules().getStandardOffset()`. You will still have to provide an instant, but it will get you the offset without any daylight savings time, that is, it is likely to be the same offset for all instants. Beware on the other hand that for many time zones it will get you an offset that is only used for a few months during winter.

Comment: For Asia/Kolkata, up to at least 1930, the offset from UTC was +05:53:20. During WWII it was +06:30. Today it is +05:30. So even though it does not change over the year, you still need to decide what time you want to get it for.

Answer (score 4):

This gets you what you want:

```
String zoneOffsetID = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata").getId();
System.out.println(zoneOffsetID);
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata").getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
System.out.println(zoneOffset);
```

... and prints:

```
Asia/Kolkata
+05:30
```

Not sure if this is the shortest/neatest/preferred way, but it works.

Comment: But this is accepting Instant.now() as a parameter in getOffset() which I don't want.

Comment: Since it is not a fixed offset in that timezone, you have to indicate for which date/time you want to know the offset.

Comment: @PrasathGovind - it is not possible to get offset without knowing what point in time you are talking about.  Even [India used different offsets in the 1940's](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/kolkata?year=1943), and in many places around the world the offset changes twice a year for daylight saving time.  See also "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 3):

As many people already told in the comments, the API doesn't have a `getOffset()` method without arguments. That's because timezones are not guaranteed to have just one single offset. They can have more than one during its history (and most of them - if not all - have it).

The API offers a way to check all these changes.

The `ZoneId` class has a `getRules()` method, that returns a `java.time.zone.ZoneRules` instance, which contains all the rules defining how the offset changes over time, for the correspondent timezone.

Let's take the timezone you used in your example and get its rules:

```
// get timezone
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
// get rules
ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
// get list of transitions (date/times when the offset changes)
List<ZoneOffsetTransition> transitions = rules.getTransitions();
for (ZoneOffsetTransition zt : transitions) {
    System.out.println(zt);
}
```

This will print all the transitions: all the date/time when there's a change in the offset. The output will be:

> Transition[Overlap at 1880-01-01T00:00+05:53:28 to +05:53:20]
>     Transition[Gap at 1941-10-01T00:00+05:53:20 to +06:30]
>     Transition[Overlap at 1942-05-15T00:00+06:30 to +05:30]
>     Transition[Gap at 1942-09-01T00:00+05:30 to +06:30]
>     Transition[Overlap at 1945-10-15T00:00+06:30 to +05:30]

Let's take a look at the last line. It says that at **October, 15<sup>th</sup> 1945** at **00h00** the offset changes from `+06:30` to `+05:30`. The clocks are shifted 1 hour back, due to the end of Daylight Saving Time in this timezone (see the [link provided by @MattJohnson in his comment](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/kolkata?year=1943))

We can test this behaviour with the following code:

```
// DST ends at 1945-10-15T00:00, setting date 1 minute before
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.of(1945, 10, 14, 23, 59, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

// in DST, offset is +06:30
System.out.println("in DST:  " + dt);

// plus 1 minute, DST ends (offset changes to +05:30)
System.out.println("not DST: " + dt.plusMinutes(1));
```

The output is:

> in DST:  1945-10-14T23:59+06:30[Asia/Kolkata]
>     not DST: 1945-10-14T23:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Note that in **Oct, 14<sup>th</sup> 23:59** the offset is `+06:30` (it's in DST), but 1 minute later (which would be **Oct, 15<sup>th</sup> 00:00**), DST ends and the clock is shifted back 1 hour, so it becomes **Oct, 14<sup>th</sup> 23:00** with a `+05:30` offset.

That's why the `getOffset()` method **must** have an `Instant` parameter: each instant in time have a different offset.

Using the dates above, you can check the offset using the `ZoneRules.getOffset` method, and `ZonedDateTime.toInstant()` method to convert the dates to an `Instant`:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.of(1945, 10, 14, 23, 59, 0, 0, zone);

// in DST, offset is +06:30
System.out.println(rules.getOffset(dt.toInstant()));

// plus 1 minute, DST ends (offset changes to +05:30)
System.out.println(rules.getOffset(dt.plusMinutes(1).toInstant()));
```

The output is:

> +06:30 
>   +05:30

---

Let's take a look again at the list of transitions for this timezone:

> Transition[Overlap at 1880-01-01T00:00+05:53:28 to +05:53:20]
>     Transition[Gap at 1941-10-01T00:00+05:53:20 to +06:30]
>     Transition[Overlap at 1942-05-15T00:00+06:30 to +05:30]
>     Transition[Gap at 1942-09-01T00:00+05:30 to +06:30]
>     Transition[Overlap at 1945-10-15T00:00+06:30 to +05:30]

The first 2 lines means that Kolkata's timezone used a `+05:53:28` before 1880, then used `+05:53:20` until 1941, when the `+06:30` offset started. Then there were some DST transitions, and nowadays it doesn't have DST and the offset is `+05:30`.

So, Kolkata's timezone can have **four** different offsets, depending on the date and time you look for. If you want to know the timezone's offset, you **must** provide an `Instant`, because the API can't just choose between all the options. To get the **current** offset (the one it's being used **today**, at this moment) you can use `Instant.now()` (as in [Robin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43716500/7605325)).

But don't forget that timezones can be changed anytime by governments, so it's not guaranteed to always be the same. Some administration might decide to change a country/region's timezone, or say that "this year we'll have DST starting tomorrow", or something like that. Just because today a timezone has no DST changes, it doesn't mean it'll always be like that.

That's why we can't have a no-argument `getOffset()` method.

---

One more thing: you can check if a timezone has offset variations:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
System.out.println(rules.isFixedOffset()); // false (not fixed = offset varies)
```

The `isFixedOffset()` method returns `true` if the timezone's offset never changes.
But even when it's `true`, the API's designers decided that `getOffset` always need an `Instant` to check what's the offset for that instant (because nobody knows if the offset will change in the future).